# Lua to android's Dex

Tags: android, lua, dex

Our team uses lua script to develop a mobile App, but LuaJ's performance isn't we needed. So I want to translate lua to android dex. to improve LuaJ performance. Has anybody done something similar?

Comment: I don't think there is a lua to dex compiler

Comment: this work is very challenge,  first analyse lua bytecode, and for-each turn to arm asm, second let luaJ support jit function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best performance you can get is to embed [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) into your Android application. That's what mobile game engines (like CoronaSDK) do.

You will need to provide Android API to LuaJIT bindings.

Comment: We did a LuaJIT experiment, through LuaJava + JNI + LuaJIT implementation. Script execution performance is very fast, but the efficiency of the project is not high. As the JNI calls too often, resulting in non-stop in Java and Lua before the two virtual machine switch.